# JavaScript Loop(Make sure my loop isn't rewriting)

Tags: javascript, loops

So I need some help saving some files that people will submit via a file upload.
Right now my code replaces it each time, but I want it to not replace each time. Like for example my user chooses a certain amount of files like 3 files, uploads them, and then chooses 1 file and uploads that as well. That would be a total of 4 files. What my code is doing now is if my user uploads 3 files, it saves the 3 files and then if they upload 1 file it gets rid of the 3 and only has one file.

I want it to not get rewritten, and have 4 files. Please help. This seem very trivial but I can't seem to get it.

```
function handleFileSelect(e) {
    if (!e.target.files) return;
    selDiv.innerHTML = "";
    var files = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var f = files[i];
        selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: what was java tagged ?

Comment: What is your files array looking like? Because your code works for me...

Comment: Hi josh this what my entire function looks like

Comment: Can you provide us an example of what is wrong ?

Comment: `function handleFileSelect(e) {`
  
  `if(!e.target.files) return;`
  
  `selDiv.innerHTML = "";`
  
  `var files = e.target.files;`
  `for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {`
   `var f = files[i];`
   
   `selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "<br/>";`

  `}`
  
 `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is you are resetting the innerHTML in the function call. I assume this function is called every time files are uploaded?

```
function handleFileSelect(e) {
    if (!e.target.files) return;
    selDiv.innerHTML = ""; // <--- this will empty the div
    var files = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var f = files[i];
        selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

If you have uploaded files, then called this function and displayed them and then upload more files and call this function it will constantly reset the innerHTML. I believe if you remove that line it will continue to append the uploaded files without overwriting the previous ones.

Comment: Awesome that was totally simple, and it worked. Yes it would empty the set every time. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem! Happy to help!

Comment: Would you happen know how to be able to delete files. For example now I have a list of files. Could I create a button to  delete them all?

Comment: Sure. You can do something like this. Take note there is extra code in here just to simulate some fake uploads. http://jsfiddle.net/cyLauhqe/